# Ruby on Rails -- The trumbowyg editor will not apper

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I put the trumbowyg JS code in my part template in my rails project:

```
- content_for :bottom_script do
  javascript:
    $('#pure-text').trumbowyg();
//...

.form-group
      = chd.text_field :cheads, class: "form-control", id: "pure-text"
```

When I into this complete template, I see the editor.

After the somone edit action run, I use `*.js.slim` file to run the JS code and render the part template in my JS code. But the editor will not apper again.

There has wrong with `$('#pure-text').trumbowyg();` code? Or other reasons?

Comment: Does it work this way: 1. Edit the content in pure-text field 2. Submit the form 3. Open browser console 4. Run `$('#pure-text').trumbowyg();` 5. Now, edit the content again?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh No use.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the script is running when expected. Add `alert('Script Loaded')` or similar above the line `$('#pure-text').trumbowyg();` and check it's firing when it should be.